# Bash script can't figure out how to concatenating white spaces

Tags: bash

I want to center a word in X spaces so I wrote this function:

```
function center {

   str=$1
   M=$2
   N=${#str}

   if (( N >= M )); then
      echo $str
      exit
   fi

   P=$((M-N))
   HP=$((P/2))

   left=""
   right=""

   for i in [1..HP]; do :

      left=" $left"
      right=" $right"

   done

   if (( (P-2*HP) == 1 )); then
      right=" "$right""
   fi

   echo "HP is $HP"



   echo "Right is |"${right}"|"
   echo "Left is |$left|"
   echo "str is |$str|"

   res=$right$str$left
   echo "$res"

}
```

Problem is not matter what I do can't get right or left to hold on to more than one whitespace. I have tried the suggestions on other answers but I can't seem to make them work. Please help.

Comment: `for i in [1..HP]` won't work; the loop will be executed just once with `i` set to `[1..HP]`. You should use a C-style for loop instead: `for (( i = 0; i < HP; ++i )); do`

Comment: You need to quote the variable to avoid combining adjacent spaces.

Comment: Thank you Benjamin W. After your correction the code worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (after some variable quoting and some other fixes):

```
function center {

   str=$1
   M=$2
   N=${#str}

   if (( N >= M )); then
      echo "$str"
      exit
   fi

   (( P=M-N  ))
   (( HP=P/2 ))

   left=$(printf '%*s' "$HP" "")
   right=$left
   (( (P-2*HP) == 1 )) && right=" "$right""

   echo "HP is $HP"

   echo "Right is |${right}|"
   echo "Left is |$left|"
   echo "str is |$str|"

   res="$right$str$left"
   echo "$res"

}
```

The `for i in [1..HP]` can not work.

A `printf '%*s' "$HP" ""` is a more idiomatic way to get `$HP` spaces.

Is better to build one variable `$left` and copy it to `$right` than to build the two.